# can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?) - iptables is not present

Tags: iptables, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nginx, ssl, certificates

I am trying to install NGINX and Certificate by following this
[enter link description here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04#:%7E:text=1%20How%20to%20Install%20and%20Configure%20Nginx%20on,...%207%20Test%20Nginx.%20...%208%20More%20items) in WSL

But at the **Step 5: Allow Nginx Traffic**, I am getting error after the command **sudo ufw allow 'nginx http'**.

The error we are facing is

```
WARN: initcaps
[Errno 2] iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

Skipping adding existing rule
```

While I listed the files in /etc/modprobe.d I didn't find iptable file

Can anyone help to resolve this.

Tried to install NGINX and SSL

Comment: You have this tagged WSL, which makes sense to me because this might be something you'd see there.  However, you don't mention WSL anywhere in the question.  Can you confirm (via question edit) whether or not you are referring to WSL?  Thanks!

Comment: Also, your link is corrupted - It's like you tried to link to both PhoenixNAP and Stack Overflow at the same time.  Was it meant to be one link or two?  Can you fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds  Thanks for the response. I'm referring to WSL and edited the same in the question. And also I have added the link of PhoenixNAP.

Comment: Sorry this one has taken me a few days to get to.  I noticed you posted on [Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1764074/1210833) as well, but let's try to keep it consolidated in one place.  It doesn't look like anyone is responding there either, so I'd recommend deleting that one.

Comment: Can you also add to your question (a) which Ubuntu release you are using, and (b) does `wsl --version` return anything other than help text, and if so, what.

Comment: I think this may be a version mismatch, but even then it's probably not going to work the way you intend.

Comment: Also, a `uname -a` to check the kernel version.  Thanks!